# js dates pass in a function

Tags: javascript, function, date, datetime

I am facing an issue in javascript dates, i want to added this lines in my GetFormattedDate function.

I try , i can't implement this logic in my function

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var myTime1 = currentdate.getHours() +':'+ (currentdate.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30') ;  //output 18:43
```

My code:

```
  function GetFormattedDate(date) {   
      var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      var day  = ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var hour =  ("0" + (date.getHours())).slice(-2);
      var min =  ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
      var seg = ("0" + (date.getSeconds())).slice(-2);

      return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" +  min + ":" + seg + " " ;
}
```

Expected output

```
`2020-05-12 01:00:00` //if minutes are 0 to 29 then show current hours reset the minutes again start with 0 like 18:00:00 and seconds become 0

`2020-05-12 01:30:00 ` //if minutes are 29 to 59 then show current hours reset the minutes again start with 30 like 18:30:00 and seconds become 0
```

Comment: What is `currentdate`? Shouldn't that be `date`?

Comment: Do you want to return both formatted times, or is this instead of what you're currently returning?

Comment: just want to change `minutes and seconds` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: eg. `2020-05-12 01:00:00` and `2020-05-12 01:30:00` (@)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar]

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string to your function. Based on the link you provided in a comment, you need to parse a string representation of a date into an actual date object: `var d = Date.parse("March 21, 2012");` Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Once you have a new `Date` object, set its seconds:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() <= 29 ? 0 : 30);
```

Now you can pass `d` to your function:

```
GetFormattedDate(d);
```

Comment: How do you know what he's passing to the function? He didn't show the caller.

Comment: can you this problem? i try but i can't solve it help me [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461189/nurchi)

Comment: can I what this problem? :) `GetFormattedDate` returns a new `string`. You need to print it or change some item's text. Try `console.log(GetFormattedDate(d));` and you should see it in your browser's JavaScript debugger. Or go to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_date_obj, learn their example and update it to your needs...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-kilby-0dcz6?file=/src/App.js [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461189/nurchi)

Comment: can you help me to this problem ? i try to solve this problem still `3 5 days` i do alot of efforts and time  [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461189/nurchi)

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, but I tried to understand what he wanted to do and tried to help :) Updating my answer to mention that it is based on an assumption that ...

Comment: thanks please help me out , i am not good in coding [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461189/nurchi)

Answer (score 0):

Do it when you set the `min` and `seg` variables

Replace the two lines

```
      var min =  ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
      var seg = ("0" + (date.getSeconds())).slice(-2);
```

with

```
      var min =  date.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30';
      var seg = '00';
```

```js
function GetFormattedDate(date) {
  var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var day = ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hour = ("0" + (date.getHours())).slice(-2);
  var min = date.getMinutes() <= 29 ? '00' : '30';
  var seg = '00';

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + seg + " ";
}

console.log(GetFormattedDate(new Date));
```

Comment: `var min =  ("0" + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2)`

Comment: They replace the two lines that set  those variables. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I had a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: sorry my mistake sec are change [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: eg. `2020-05-12 01:30:00` `2020-05-12 02:00:00`

Comment: I've added an executable snippet.

Comment: thanks i ask more thing? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-kilby-0dcz6?file=/src/App.js [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: can you help me to this problem ? i try to solve this problem still `2 3 days` i do alot of efforts and time [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: i am not in coding, help me [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Comment: I don't know what you're asking me to help with. If you have a new problem, post a new question. BTW, why do you end every comment with "@"?